# How to recover an extension via the Ext functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Consider the $R$-modules $A$ and $B$ and suppose we would like to classify extensions of $A$ by $B$, i.e we would like to classify all $R$-modules which fit in to the middle slot of the following SES, 
$$ 0 \to B \to ? \to A \to 0 $$ 
up to isomorphism of extension. We know such modules are classified by the group $Ext_R^1(A,B)$.

Suppose I know the generators of $Ext_R^1(A,B)$ as an $R$-module. How do I use these generators to recover extensions?

I am looking for a very easy example.

Comment: This depends on how you computed such Ext group. If you used a projective resolution, for example, there is a way to recover extensions from cocycles. But without some more information, there's no definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be a comment, but I don't have the rep.

Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0, exercise VIII.6.22 walks through this in depth, giving quite a few hints. I'm sure there are other references, but that's where I remember seeing it done.